# Printable keyboard layout for Ukrainian on a MacBook Pro

Tags: ukrainian, keyboard-layout

I want to be able to type efficiently in Ukrainian on my MacBook Pro computer.

If possible, I want to just print out a piece of paper that's at the same scale as my actual keyboard, and lay it over my keyboard when I need to use it.

Do such resources exist, and if so, how do I search for them? What keywords should I use?

I can find a diagram of what a Ukrainian keyboard more or less looks like at http://en.ukrlandia.com.ua/russian-ukrainian-layout-mac/ , but it doesn't look like an exact match.

**Update**: Turns out what I want, if purchased, is called a "keyboard cover".

Comment: Hmm, that's not really a language learning question, is it? I know it is useful when you learn Ukrainian, but it is essentially a computer question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic. See Christophe Strobbe's comment.

Answer (score 6):

## A bit cynical answer

Once you've installed a keyboard layout on Mac, you can print it out via the toolbar button on the view layout window.

[image: Ukrainian layout on Mac]

## A more constructive :-) answer

The standard Mac layout for Ukrainian is awful:

- it has `і` and `и` swapped;
- it has comma and period in unusual places <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd>;
- apostrophe is misplaced;

The solution is [**Ukrainian Typographic Layout**](http://gagadget.com/another/4076-ukrainskaya-tipografskaya-raskladka-klaviaturyi/) (Windows/Mac)  based on Ilya Birman's [typographic layout](http://ilyabirman.net/projects/typography-layout/) (the latter is a huge topic, see below).

I actually use it myself (a derivative of). It is a combined Ukrainian/Byelorussian/Russian layout. For example, I have Ukrainian `і` placed on <kbd>S</kbd>, while Russian `ы` under <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>.
At the same time, UA/BY/RU `в` is under <kbd>D</kbd>, while <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> gives me a Byelorussian `ў`.

**Note.** There are different layouts available, they differ on what is "default" and what us under <kbd>AltGr</kbd> — either it is Ukrainian or Russian, depending on what language you type more.

**Offtopic,** in addition, this layout quickly makes you familiar with “extended” punctuation marks like «double quotes», ½ fractions, and so on…

Once you've got it installed, just print it as specified in the above chapter.

---

Further reading on Ilya Birman's layout:

- [Main site](http://ilyabirman.net/projects/typography-layout/)
- [Order a printed poster](http://ilyabirman.ru/projects/typography-layout/poster/) (attn: paywall)
- [Article on Smashing Magazine](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/04/typography-keyboard-layout-download-now/)

**Caveat:** most sites on the topic are in Russian, so you need some online translator to employ.

Comment: The Russian browser "Yandex" [www.yandex.ru]  includes an outstanding multi-language Translator function ("Пепеводцик") that can accessed from the browser's main/home page.  The dictionary-like definitions in the translations (e.g., Russian<->Ukrainian) include grammar, usage, synonyms, and antonyms.

Comment: @К.КеллоггСмиф, I would not recommend Yandex browser if you care about the malware, *and especially* if it detects a Ukrainian keyboard layout (or just an IP address) on your computer, considering the events that occur since February, 2014. It could be an option before that, perhaps.

Comment: I do appreciate your comment with your concerns about matters that worry you but regretfully, I'm not qualified to help you overcome your fears.

Comment: can you link your combined Ua-By-Ru keyboard?

Comment: @DimaLituiev, I'm afraid that no. Downloading binaries from unidentified strangers on the Internet is way too unsafe. However, you may download the standard Birman's version and then modify it for yourself. I think that both Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator (Windows) and Ukelele (MacOS) are free software.